# Cut text in echo from mysql

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a problem.

This is my bash script:

```
while read fieldA
do
  echo "$fieldA"
done < <(mysql --user root -proot test -Bse "SELECT description From Object LIMIT 1
```

Echo:

```
"Kościół z 1938 roku. Powstał ku czci żołnierzy niemieckich poległych w czasie I Wojny Światowej. Szczyt frontonu zdobiły trzy postacie: św. Brunona, krzyżaka i ninPo wojnie postacie te zatynkowano. W latach 70-tych w tym miejscu umieszczono mozaikę przedstawiającą Św. Brunona w otoczeniu atakujących go wojowników pruskich."
```

But in mysql this text is:

```
'Kościół z 1938 roku. Powstał ku czci żołnierzy niemieckich poległych w czasie I Wojny Światowej. Szczyt frontonu zdobiły trzy postacie: św. Brunona, krzyżaka i niemieckiego żołnierza z karabinem w ręku.\r\n\r\nPo wojnie postacie te zatynkowano. W latach 70-tych w tym miejscu umieszczono mozaikę przedstawiającą Św. Brunona w otoczeniu atakujących go wojowników pruskich.'
```

I think problem is with "\r\n\r\n"

I want have in ECHO the same text as mysql (with all \r\n\r\n.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes in echo otherwise \n\r are gonna be break lines

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you have in your mysql column.

If it is a carriage return, linefeed pair, then the terminal already interprets these characters properly. If you want to show them as escape sequences anyway, you can replace them with the characters `\`, `r` or `\` and `n` respectively.

If you have a literal `\r\n` in your string, i.e. four characters `\`, `r`, `\` and `n`, then you can try disabling the interpretation with `-E`

```
echo -E "$fieldA"
```